# Execute SELECT using SQLExecDirect

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

I have MSSQL database service with created database `ggg` that contain table `t1`

Trying to execute `SELECT` statement

```
 RetCode = SQLExecDirect(hStmt,wszInput, SQL_NTS);
```

content of `wszInput` is `select * from ggg.t1`

Have error in output:

```
[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ggg.t1'. (208)
SQL COMMAND>select * from DB.ggg.t1
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular syntax you need to separate the database, *schema*, and then table.  Your code should be (assuming that `T1` is in the default schema of `dbo`)

`SELECT * FROM ggg.dbo.t1`

If you type `y`, SQL assumes that you are talking about a table or view in the default (usually dbo) schema of the currently connected database.

If you type `x.y`, SQL assumes you are talking about the `y` table in the `x` schema of the currently connected database.

If you type `x.dbo.y`, SQL will look in the `dbo` schema of the `x` database for the table named `y`.